# How can I generate a random math operator? (Eclipse)

Tags: java

I am wondering how to generate a random math operator (+*-/) in eclipse. OR how I can output ("What is " number1 " + " + number2)

I have already tried ("What is " number1 " + " + number2)

//Random number generator

```
    firstNumber=number.nextInt(10-1)+1;
    secondNumber=number.nextInt(10-1)+1;
```

//Output

```
    System.out.println("What is " + firstNumber + secondNumber);
```

I expect an output of "what is number1 + number2"
                  eg; "What is 8 + 5"

Comment: This will return you a random operator: "+*-/".charAt(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4));

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("What is " + firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

To print something like "What is 5 + 8" or * or / or - randomly you can do:

```
System.out.println(
    "What is "
    + firstNumber 
    + " "
    + "+-*/".charAt((new Random()).nextInt(4))
    + " "
    + secondNumber);
```

The `new Random()` creates a random object to which then you apply `.nextInt(4)` which generates a random number from 0 to 3.

You apply `charAt()` to "+-*/" with a random location 0 to 3 defined by the random number. This allows you to return a +, -, *, or / randomly.

Lastly, you concatenate "What is " with the first number with the random operator with the second number.

Don't forget to `import java.util.Random;`